# Calculating the center of subObjects in Maxscript

Tags: maxscript

I have a set of polygons selected (called `myFaces`). After that, I know I must convert the selection to vertices with

```
verts = polyop.getVertsUsingFace $ myFaces
```

and then apply any transformation using the center of those verts.

How do I calculate the center of those vertices?

Edit: I specifically need to use vertices and not faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no shortcut, you have to calculate the center yourself, i.e.

```
fn getSubObjCenter obj verts center:[0, 0, 0] =
(
    for vert in verts do
        center += polyOp.getVert obj vert node:obj
    center / verts.numberSet
)

obj = selection[1]
verts = polyOp.getVertsUsingFace obj #all
getSubObjCenter obj verts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the center of faces using polyop.getFaceCenter

See http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2015/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_B40F84EA_5F19_45B6_AA7C_0ADC77708BBE_htm